# LinearLayout items display and orientation change

Tags: android, xml, layout, orientation

I want to ask if is there any possible way to make Linear Layout display items like display: inline-flex in CSS?

By that I mean when I change orientation of device I want to (in horizontal mode) display items inline (also when one of item have visibility set to gone I want change other items width by percentage e.g. 3 items - 30% per item, 2 items - 50%, one item 100%).

In vertical mode, items should be displayed one under one.

By the way - how to prevent reset of view when it's being changed programaticlly? (I have problem with it, because when I fill input box with text - the text disappears when I change device orientation and so on).

Comment: Check out the `layout_weight` attribute for child items inside a `LinearLayout`: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Comment: layout_weight ain't fits my expectations or it could fit, but I'd like to know in the same time how to prevent reset of view.

Comment: You can't 'prevent reset of view' (unless you entirely prevent orientation changes), but you can save the state of your data by overriding your Activity's `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`. That will be called automatically by the system when the orientation is changing, and then pass that `Bundle` back to you in `onCreate(Bundle)`. From there you can check if the `Bundle` is null and respond accordingly.

Comment: To be sure - if I change orientation, animated element will reset his animation key as well?

Comment: Correct, unless you use `onSavedInstance` to set a flag, and check for that flag in `onCreate` before running the animation

Comment: Oh boy. Okay, that's it, thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When you hiding view, you must use visibility gone then it will take equal space.